# Nao consigo fazer um butao de update para mudar os dados do perfil do utilizador

Tags: php

```
//FUNCAO DE DAR UPDATE
public function update_perfil($id)
 {
    $bd = new Database();
      // Cria uma hash para o registo cliente
      $purl = store::criarHash();
    
     $parametros = [
         // NOME DOS PARAMETROS = NOME DOS CAMPOS
         ':id' => strtolower(trim($id)),
          // NOME DOS PARAMETROS = NOME DOS CAMPOS
          ':email' => strtolower(trim($_POST['text_email'])),
          // ENCRIPTAÇÃO DA SENHA
          ':senha' => password_hash($_POST['text_senha_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
          ':Nome' => trim($_POST['text_nome']),
          ':Morada' => trim($_POST['text_morada']),
          ':CodigoPostal' => trim($_POST['text_cdpostal']),
          ':Localidade' => trim($_POST['text_localidade']),
          ':Telemovel' => trim($_POST['text_telemovel']),
          ':purl' => $purl,
          ':activo' => 1 // 0,
     ];
     $resultados = $bd->update("UPDATE * FROM  clientes  WHERE id_cliente= :id",$parametros);
            return $resultados;
      // Retorna o purl criado
      return $purl;
     
 }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

> <sup>Quando for postar uma pergunta sempre informe o máximo possível de detalhes sobre o erro e outras informações que possam ajudar a resolver seu problema.</sup>

Olhando apenas seu código o único erro que vejo incialmente é o seu comando SQL do `UPDATE` que está errado. O formato correto de um `UPDATE` é:

```sql
-- UPDATE <your_table_name> SET <colum_name> = <value> WHERE <conditions>;
UPDATE `clientes` SET <email_column> = :email, <pass_column> = :pass, <... e assim por diante> WHERE `id_cliente` = :id;
```

Comment: Você já tem reputação para comentar.